# Authentication error while sending mail with Oauth2 and nodemailer

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, backend, nodemailer

I am attempting to send an email from the user's Gmail account. The user signs in with OAuth2 and grants permission to compose emails, and the access and refresh tokens are stored in the database. However, while sending the email, I am encountering an error:
code: 'EENVELOPE',
response: '530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. For more information, go to\n' +
'530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g11-20020a170902f74b00b001d4ceb32787sm7910624plw.78 - gsmtp',
responseCode: 530,
command: 'MAIL FROM'

This is the function used to send the mail .

```
export async function sendMail(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        // Temporarily checking sending mail
        const user: userInterface | null = await User.findOne({ "email": "chahatsagar2003@gmail.com" });
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ "message": "User not found" });

        
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service : "gmail",
            auth: {
                type: "OAuth2",
                user: process.env.EMAIL,
                accessToken : user.acessToken,
                clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
            }
        } as nodemailer.TransportOptions);

        const mailOptions = {
            from: user.email,
            to: "email here",
            subject: "Hello Amit ",
            text: "This email is sent from the command line",
            html: `<p>‍♀️  &mdash; This is a <b>test email</b> from <a href="https://digitalinspiration.com">Digital Inspiration</a>.</p>`,
        };

        const info : any = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

        return res.status(200).json({ "message": "Email sent successfully" });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ "message": "Server side error" });
    }
}
```